# CSS Flexbox fill when content available

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a TODO App. This TODO app shows tasks horizontally for the user. In a normal case we have the task which has to be done, with a click on it the user can mark it as done.

However, I now wanted to add the option to assign a due date to it.

What I want to achieve is:

- Have the todo text shown in the div box
- If a date is given, add the date to the right side of the box

My current code is as following:

```
.box-task .task-text {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.box-task .task-date {
 font-size: 13px;
 margin-top: 9px;
 color: rgb(50, 138, 214);
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
 flex: 1 0 0;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
```

My HTML code is (in mix with Laravel blade), I hope you get the idea of what I want to achieve

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-task-text" style="height:35px;">
    <div class="task-checkbox-checked" data-id="1"></div>
        <span class="task-text">Test</span>
        <span class="task-date">23-05-1995</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve it that the date is always shown on the right side with its own width and the text does get smaller/bigger based on if the date was added?

Comment: Currently, your question is not a question. It's a statement. You want to achieve something. Good luck! If you need help with anything, edit your question stating the following: what you expect, what you get, what makes you think your current code should work.

Comment: Oh lol sorry. I edited it. My question is how am I able to achieve that the text is always shown on the right side and the left side text is always based on the width which is available (and doesnt cut the date, move to new row, ... if added)

Comment: What you use in backend is irrelevant, since the question is about frontend. Please update your snippet with the outcome of your backend (the actual HTML markup rendered in your page). Ideally, it should be a [mcve] (live snippet), linking all required resources to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Edited all the code out.

Comment: Well, there are three issues with it: **1.** It's not a live snippet (use `<>` button to add one and add each code type to its panel). Also link the libraries used from CDN sources (see point 2). **2.** We don't know what libraries/versions you use. I can see you're using Bootstrap but I have no idea what version. When it comes to CSS, it matters. A lot. **3.** Your markup is not valid. You are opening fewer `<div>`s than closing. All the above prevent me (or anyone else, for that matter) from experiencing and understanding your issue.

Comment: At this point it is clear you are having difficulties creating a live snippet. I created one, on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/vf8s41rr/) but I had to make assumptions about your code. Please update it so it reproduces your problem. Are you trying to display the tile and the date on a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From everything available so far in your question, I assume the following:

- you're trying to display a list of tasks
- each task should be displayed on a single row, with a title on left and date on the right side
- if the title doesn't fit available space, it should be cut with ellipsis effect.
- you're using Bootstrap v3.

If the above is true, this is what you're looking for:

```css
.box-task .task-text {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.box-task .task-date {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  color: rgb(50, 138, 214);
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.col-task-text {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row box-task">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-task-text" style="height:35px;">
      <div class="task-checkbox-checked" data-id="1"></div>
      <span class="task-text">Test</span>
      <span class="task-date">23-05-1995</span>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-task-text" style="height:35px;">
      <div class="task-checkbox-checked" data-id="2"></div>
      <span class="task-text">Test</span>
      <span class="task-date">23-05-1995</span>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-task-text" style="height:35px;">
      <div class="task-checkbox-checked" data-id="3"></div>
      <span class="task-text">Test with a lot more text, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Test with a lot more text, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
      <span class="task-date">23-05-1995</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There were quite a few details I needed to fix, but the most important ones were:

- you need `display:inline-block` (or `block`) for `text-overflow:ellipsis` to work
- the `display:flex` needs to be on the parent, not on the children for `flex:{grow} {shrink} {basis};` shorthand to work.
  If you're going to use `flexbox` you need to read CSS documentation*** available on each of its properties. The most important part is to understand which props go on parent and which on children and how they all work together.

*** [Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) (oficial spec). You might find [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) useful.

The rest are details.

---

If the above is not what you're looking for, please update your question with all the info I had to assume and, if I can help, I'll update my answer. If not, I'll delete it.